# Using a Mysql result from NodeJS rather than slurping rows

Tags: mysql, node.js

TLDR; How do I `SELECT` on a Mysql table with Node.js without slurping the results? (If you say `SELECT COUNT(id)` then use `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`, no, that's silly. I want to HOLD the query result object and poke it after, not hammer the database to death re-`SELECT`ing every few seconds. Some of these queries will take several seconds to run!)

What: I want to run a Mysql query on a nodejs service and basically attach the `MYSQL_RES` to the client's session context.

Why: The queries in question may yield tens of thousands of results. I'll only have 1 demanding client at a time, and the UI will only display ~30 results at a time in a scrollable/flickable list view.

How: In Qt it's standard practice to use a `QSqlModel` for circumstances such as this. Basically if you have a list (view) with this type of model attached, it will only "read" the results pertinent to the visible area. As the view is scrolled down it populates it with more results.

But: The NodeJS asynchronous method is lovely, but I have yet to find a way to get ONLY the result object (sans rows), and a respective method of "picking out" result rows or a span thereof arbitrarily.

Comment: How is your problem different than a standard pagination issue?

Comment: What about [_"Piping results with Streams2"_](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#piping-results-with-streams2)?

Comment: @Burhan It isn't, it is a pagination issue.

Comment: @wilx That's better, but it's still a linear stream offering no method of seeking.